# Vuejs emit click from component to main vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to emit an click Event from my component to my main vue instance but I am able to solve it. Currently I get no message in my console so it does not Event go to that function so Code Looks like this so far:

```
// component LeftUserListTileComponent
<template>
    <v-list-tile @click="$emit('toggleLeftUserPanel')">
        <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>exit_to_app</v-icon>
        </v-list-tile-action>
        <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>User Settings</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>
    </v-list-tile>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
            }
        },
        methods:{
            toggleLeftUserPanel () {
                // what to do here?
            }
    };
</script>

Vue.component('left-user-list-tile', require('./components/LeftUserListTileComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('left-user-panel', require('./components/LeftUserPanelComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    props: {
      source: String
    },

    data: {
        leftUserPanel: null
    },

    toggleLeftUserPanel () {
        console.log("In toggleLeftUserPanel func");
        this.leftUserPanel != this.leftUserPanel;
    }


});
```

Comment: Where are you actually listening to the emitted event?

Comment: I am trying to listen to it after clicking so at the @click ...

Comment: Please review this to see how to actually listen to an emitted value: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event

Comment: @Stephan-v ok I changed my Code but how do I Change the value leftUserPanel from my component emit?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? It works? If yes, mark an answer as valid in order to mark as resolved and keep S.O clean. If no, try updating the question and we will try to help you

Answer (score 0):

If you emit directly the event when clicking, in the first `toggleLeftUserPanel ()` you should do nothing more.

In order to work, you should declare what you expect from `parent` element when receiving an **toggleLeftUserPanel** `event` from it's childrens, like:

```
<toggle-left-user-panel @toggleLeftUserPanel='togglePanel' />
```

And then in the parent define this method in `methods`:

```
methods(){
    togglePanel() {
         //your action here
    }
}
```

In this way, the parent-child communication is enabled and the parent should react to the children `emit` event.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to emit an event you need to set this inside your component. If you only interested fetching a click when a user click on the title you should be able to use @click.native:

```
<v-list-tile @click.native="console.log('Title is clicked!')">
...
```